# Removing Blank Strings from a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Attempting to remove rows in which a Spark dataframe column contains blank strings. Originally did `val df2 = df1.na.drop()` but it turns out many of these values are being encoded as `""`.

I'm stuck using Spark 1.3.1 and also cannot rely on DSL. (Importing spark.implicit_ isn't working.)

Comment: what do you want to do with blank strings ? drop the line ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Removing things from a dataframe requires `filter()`.

```
newDF = oldDF.filter("colName != ''")
```

or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: How can I write this thing using Where clause

Comment: `WHERE colName IS NOT NULL` or `WHERE colName IS NOT EMPTY` ... i think.

Comment: Or, with DataFrames/Datasets, `oldDF.filter($"colName" =!= "")`. Don't forget to `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._`

Comment: Works for PySpark too!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone dont want to drop the records with blank strings, but just convvert the blank strings to some constant value.

```
val newdf = df.na.replace(df.columns,Map("" -> "0")) // to convert blank strings to zero
newdf.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df.filter(!($"col_name"===""))
```

It filters out the columns where the value of "col_name" is "" i.e. nothing/blankstring. I'm using the match filter and then inverting it by "!"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to spark So I don't know if below mentioned code is more complex or not but it works.

Here we are creating udf which is converting blank values to null.

```
sqlContext.udf().register("convertToNull",(String abc) -> (abc.trim().length() > 0 ? abc : null),DataTypes.StringType);
```

After above code you can use "convertToNull" (works on string) in select clause and make all fields null which are blank and than use .na().drop().

```
crimeDataFrame.selectExpr("C0","convertToNull(C1)","C2","C3").na().drop()
```

**Note :** You can use same approach in scala.
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-udfs.html